# SQL : Select longest and unique route

Tags: sql, sqlgeometry

I have a table that contains the route's GPS traces and I want to select only unique and longest routes.

Table looks like:

```
route_id        gpstrace
route1      [[long,lat], [long,lat],... ]
route2      [[long,lat], [long,lat],... ]
route3      [[long,lat], [long,lat],... ]
route19     [[long,lat], [long,lat],... ]
```

In `route_id` column there is possibility that `route1`, `route2` and `route3` are same but `route1` is little bit longer than `route2` and `route3`. So I want to return `route1`.
Similarly I want to return all unique and longest route from the table.

I tried:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182246/sql-server-select-all-polygons-nested-within-a-larger-polygon

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96037/sql-geometry-query-similar-to-select-by-centroid

Can anyone help me with SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE in MySQL:

```
with recursive cte(r, d, c, gpstrace) as (
    select t.route_id, 6371*acos(cos(radians(json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[0][0]')))
     * cos(radians(json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[1][0]')))
     * cos(radians(json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[0][1]') - json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[1][1]')))
     + sin(radians(json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[0][0]')))
     * sin(radians(json_extract(t.gpstrace, '$[1][0]')))), 1, t.gpstrace from testtable t
    union all
    select c.r, c.d + 6371*acos(cos(radians(json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c, '][0]'))))
      * cos(radians(json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c+1, '][0]'))))
      * cos(radians(json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c, '][1]')) - json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c+1, '][1]'))))
      + sin(radians(json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c, '][0]'))))
      * sin(radians(json_extract(c.gpstrace, concat('$[', c.c+1, '][0]'))))), c.c + 1, c.gpstrace
    from cte c
    where c.c + 1 < json_length(c.gpstrace) 
),
results(r, d) as (select r, d from cte where c + 1 >= json_length(gpstrace))
select * from results r where r.d = (select max(r1.d) from results r1);
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be52b1d4678308ea532e5f4fb1a77b8f).